# What's causing a Windows 8 desktop certification warning on Multi user session test

Tags: windows-8, desktop-application

I have a desktop application that attempts to limit the user to one instance per session (so each user/remote desktop connection can run a copy)

I do this by creating an EventWaitHandle with a "Local\..." prefix on the event name, and if isn't created, I exit the program.

The warning from the verifier tool looks like this:

WARNING

Multi user session test

• Warning: The multi user session test detected the following errors:◦An error occurred while performing the testing process.

• Impact if not fixed: Multiple users might not be able to launch the app in concurrent sessions.

• How to fix:  Make sure that the app doesn’t block multiple concurrent sessions, either locally or remotely. The app must not depend on global mutexes or other named-objects to check for or block multiple concurrent sessions. If the app can’t allow multiple concurrent sessions per user, use per-user or per-session namespaces for mutexes or other named-objects. See link below for more information: 
 Remote Desktop Services programming guidelines 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/aa383490(v=vs.85).aspx

Any idea on what this error means, and how to get rid of it?

I've tested the program while logged into multiple accounts, and it correctly detects that the program is not running on the new session, despite running on a previous one.

Is there a way to get more detailed descriptions of the failures?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem to solve. You can look at `C:\Users\<your name>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\AppCertKit` to get the logs, especially `post_process_trace_MultiUserSessionTest_????_????.txt` and `Log_MultiUserSessionTest_POSTINSTALL.xml`. I have read them but it is not helping. You can post yours and then we can try to figure out what happened.

Answer (score 1):

[this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/9de5fc69-51c4-4239-907b-65d652829f9c/wack-multi-user-registry-check-error-the-application-did-not-install-any-shortcuts) suggests that there is a bug in Windows Application Certification Kit (WACK) 2.2 and it is resolved in WACK 3.0 available for Windows 8.1 Preview. I chose to ignore this particular warning for now.

Answer (score 0):

Set for user (choice user or machine) when you run Windows App Cert

Comment: It's a per machine install, so choosing user wouldn't make sense would it?